# org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied when trying to access S3 bucket through s3n URI using Hadoop Java APIs on EC2

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tomcat7

### Scenario

I create an AWS IAM role called "my-role" specifying EC2 as trusted entity, i.e. using the trust relationship policy document:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The role has the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:GetBucketCORS",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetBucketLogging",
        "s3:GetBucketNotification",
        "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
        "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
        "s3:GetBucketTagging",
        "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
        "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
        "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
        "s3:ListBucketVersions",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:RestoreObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I launch an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2014.09.1) from the command line using AWS CLI, specifying "my-role" as instance profile and everything works out fine. I verify that the instance effectively assumes "my-role", by running:

- `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` to query for instance metadata, from which I get the response `my-role`;
- `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/my-role` from which I get temporary credentials associated to "my-role".

An example of such credentials retrieval response is something like:

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2015-01-19T10:37:35Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "an-access-key-id",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "a-secret-access-key",
  "Token" : "a-token",
  "Expiration" : "2015-01-19T16:47:09Z"
}
```

- `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/` from which I correctly get a list containing the first subdirectory(ies) under "my-bucket". *(The AWS CLI comes installed and configured by default when launching this AMI. EC2 instance and S3 bucket are within the same AWS account)*

I run/install a Tomcat7 server and container on such instance, on which I deploy a J2EE 1.7 servlet with no issues.

Such servlet should download on the local file system a file from an S3 bucket, in particular from `s3://my-bucket/custom-path/file.tar.gz` using **Hadoop Java APIs**. *(Please, note that I tried hadoop-common artifact 2.4.x, 2.5.x, 2.6.x with no positive results. I'm gonna post below the exception I get when using 2.5.x)*

Within the servlet, I retrieve fresh credentials from the instance metadata URL above mentioned and use them to configure my Hadoop Java API instance:

```java
... 
Path path = new Path("s3n://my-bucket/");
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", path.toString());
conf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", myAwsAccessKeyId);
conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", myAwsSecretAccessKey);
conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSessionToken", mySessionToken);
...
```

Obviously, `myAwsAccessKeyId`, `myAwsSecretAccessKey`, and `mySessionToken` are Java variables that I previously set with the actual values.
Then, I effectively get a FileSystem instance, using:

```java
FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
```

I am able to retrieve all the configuration related to the FileSystem (fs.getconf().get(key-name)) and verify everything is configured as assumed.

### Problem

I cannot download `s3://my-bucket/custom-path/file.tar.gz` using:

```java
...
fs.copyToLocalFile(false, new Path(path.toString()+"custom-path/file.tar.gz"), outputLocalPath);
...
```

If I use hadoop-common 2.5.x I get the `IOException`:

> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
>   s3n://my-bucket/custom-path/file.tar.gz   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:449)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:427)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.handleException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:181)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy12.retrieveMetadata(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:467)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1968)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1937)
>   ...

If I use hadoop-common 2.4.x, I get a `NullPointerException`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:433)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1968)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1937)
>   ...

Just for the records, if DON'T set any aws credential, I get:

> AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the
>   username or password (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the
>   fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties
>   (respectively).

### Final notes

- If I try to download the file from the very same URI (but s3 in place of s3n) using AWS CLI commands from the instance, I have NO PROBLEMS AT ALL.
- If I try to download an Hadoop distribution (like 2.4.1 from https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.4.1/), unzip it, retrieve the temporary AWS credentials from the instance metadata URL and try to run `<hadoop-dir>/bin/hadoop fs -cp s3n://<aws-access-key-id>:<aws-secret-access-key>@my-bucket/custom-path/file.tar.gz .` I get, once again, a NPE:

> Fatal internal error java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.listStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:479)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.getDirectoryContents(PathData.java:268)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.recursePath(Command.java:347)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Ls.processPathArgument(Ls.java:96)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:260)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:244)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:190)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:154)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:255)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:308)

Sorry for the long post, I just tried to be as much detailed as I could. Thanks for any eventual help out here.

Answer (score 8):

You are using STS/temporary AWS credentials; these do not appear to be currently supported by the `s3` or `s3n` `FileSystem` implementations in hadoop.

AWS STS/temporary credentials include not only an (access key, secret key), but additionally a session token.  The hadoop `s3` and `s3n` `FileSystem`(s) do not yet support inclusion of the session token (i.e. your configuration of `fs.s3n.awsSessionToken` is unsupported and ignored by the `s3n` `FileSystem`.

From [AmazonS3 - Hadoop Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3)...

*(Note there is no mention of `fs.s3.awsSessionToken`)*:

> **Configuring to use s3/ s3n filesystems**
>
> Edit your `core-site.xml` file to include your S3 keys
>
> ```
>    <property>
>      <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
>      <value>ID</value>
>    </property>
>
>    <property>
>      <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
>      <value>SECRET</value>
>    </property>
> ```

If you take a look at [S3Credentials.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3/S3Credentials.java) from apache/hadoop on github.com, you'll notice that the notion of a session token is completely missing from the representation of S3 credentials.

There was a patch submitted to address this limitation (detailed [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9680)); however, it hasn't been integrated.

---

If you are using AWS IAM Instance Roles, you may want to explore using the new `s3a` `FileSystem` that was added in Hadoop 2.6.0.  It claims to have support for IAM role-based authentication (i.e. you wouldn't have to explicitly specify the keys at all).

A Hadoop JIRA ticket describes how to configure the `s3a` `FileSystem`:

From https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10400 :

> `fs.s3a.access.key` - Your AWS access key ID (omit for role authentication)
>   `fs.s3a.secret.key` - Your AWS secret key (omit for role authentication)