# PySpark using IAM roles to access S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-iam

I'm wondering if PySpark supports S3 access using IAM roles. Specifically, I have a business constraint where I have to assume an AWS role in order to access a given bucket. This is fine when using boto (as it's part of the API), but I can't find a definitive answer as to if PySpark supports this out of the box.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to assume a role when running in standalone mode locally and point my SparkContext to that s3 path. I've seen that non-IAM calls usually follow :

```
spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]').setAppName('MyApp')
sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
rdd = sc.textFile('s3://<MY-ID>:<MY-KEY>@some-bucket/some-key')
```

Does something like this exist for providing IAM info? :

```
rdd = sc.textFile('s3://<MY-ID>:<MY-KEY>:<MY-SESSION>@some-bucket/some-key')
```

or

```
rdd = sc.textFile('s3://<ROLE-ARN>:<ROLE-SESSION-NAME>@some-bucket/some-key')
```

If not, what are the best practices for working with IAM creds? Is it even possible?

I'm using Python 1.7 and PySpark 1.6.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

IAM role for accessing `s3` is only support by **s3a**, because it is using AWS SDK.

You need to put `hadoop-aws` JAR and `aws-java-sdk` JAR (and third-party Jars in its package) into your CLASSPATH.

[hadoop-aws](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/) link.

[aws-java-sdk](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/) link.

Then set this in `core-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 5):

IAM Role-based access to files in S3 is supported by Spark, you just need to be careful with your config.  Specifically, you need:

- Compatible versions of  `aws-java-sdk` and `hadoop-aws`.  This is [quite brittle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979564/1779128) so only specific combinations work.
- You must use the `S3AFileSystem`, not `NativeS3FileSystem`.  The former permits role based access, whereas the later only allows user credentials.

To find out which combinations work, go to `hadoop-aws` on mvnrepository [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws).  Click through the version of `hadoop-aws` you have look for the `version` of the `aws-java-sdk` compile dependency.

To find out what version of `hadoop-aws` you are using, in PySpark you can execute:

```
sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion()
```

where `sc` is the SparkContext

This is what worked for me:

```
import os
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1 pyspark-shell'

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

hadoopConf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")

spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark.read.csv("s3a://mybucket/spark/iris/",header=True)
df.show()
```

It's the specific combination of `aws-java-sdk:1.7.4` and `hadoop-aws:2.7.1` that made it work.  There is good guidance on troubleshooting s3a access [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md)

Specially note that

> Randomly changing hadoop- and aws- JARs in the hope of making a problem "go away" or to gain access to a feature you want, will not lead to the outcome you desire.

Here is a [useful post](https://github.com/bweigel/local-spark-s3-access/blob/6857434e16ca0ab382f684bff280f385fdc5343c/python/README.md) containing further information.

Here's some more [useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500842/hadoop-aws-versions-compatibility) about compatibility between the java libraries

I was trying to get this to work in the [jupyter pyspark notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/pyspark-notebook/Dockerfile).  Note that the `aws-hadoop` version had to match the hadoop install in the Dockerfile i.e. [here](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/1145fb1198b2a51ac01065ea8714b327d022bce6/pyspark-notebook/Dockerfile#L11).

Comment: This post https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/aws/iam-roles.html suggests in the FAQ that s3n can be used with spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.impl com.databricks.s3a.S3AFileSystem . Any ideas if this is databricks specific, or if it can work with pyspark?

Comment: where are you giving AWS IAM role details?

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop 2.8+'s s3a connector supports IAM roles via a new credential provider; It's not in the Hadoop 2.7 release.

To use it you need to change the credential provider.

```
fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider = org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider
fs.s3a.access.key = <your access key>
fs.s3a.secret.key = <session secret>
fs.s3a.session.token = <session token>
```

What is in Hadoop 2.7 (and enabled by default) is the picking up of the `AWS_` environment variables.

If you set the [AWS env vars](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html) for session login on your local system *and the remote ones* then they should get picked up.

I know its a pain, but as far as the Hadoop team are concerned Hadoop 2.7 shipped mid-2016 and we've done a lot since then, stuff which we aren't going to backport

Comment: This is a great answer. Helped me solve one of those forbidden access issues. Thanks

Comment: Thnak you, where are you giving role details . where do we get session details from?

Comment: look at the hadoop s3a docs for these details

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach in [Locally reading S3 files through Spark (or better: pyspark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443911/locally-reading-s3-files-through-spark-or-better-pyspark).

However I've had better luck with setting environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` etc) in Bash ... pyspark will automatically pick these up for your session.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I'm convinced this is not yet supported as evidenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28160821/6101120).

Others have suggested taking a more manual approach (see [this blog post](https://wrightturn.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/getting-spark-data-from-aws-s3-using-boto-and-pyspark/)) which suggests to list s3 keys using boto, then parallelize that list using Spark to read each object.

The problem here (and I don't yet see how they themselves get around it) is that the s3 objects given back from listing within a bucket are not serializable/pickle-able (remember : it's suggested that these objects are given to the workers to read in independent processes via map or flatMap). Furthering the problem is that the boto s3 client *itself* isn't serializable (which is reasonable in my opinion).

What we're left with is the only choice of recreating the assumed-role s3 client *per file*, which isn't optimal or feasible past a certain point.

If anyone sees any flaws in this reasoning or an alternative solution/approach, I'd love to hear it.